# Spring Boot configuration with pre-set default values?

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration

working with configurations in Spring Boot 2.1, I am circling around the question of how to implement a proper configuration management, where I have both parameters from a properties file and hardcoded values als configuration parameters, as well as default values for each parameter. Finally, I would need to have some sort of "integrity check" for each parameter, e.g. checking if an integer is in a specified range.

While this seems easy and simple enough, the realization for this is quite bloated and counterintuitive.

My minimal example looks like this:

application.yml

```
param1=42
```

Config.java

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.yml")
public class Config {
    private static final int DEFAULT_PARAM1 = 1;
    private static final int PARAM1_MIN = 1;
    private static final int PARAM1_MAX = 5;

    @Autowired
    private int param1;

    public int getParam1() {
        return param1;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        if(param1 == null || !checkParam1(param1)) param1 = DEFAULT_PARAM1;
    }

    public boolean checkParam1(param)
    {
        if(param > PARAM1_MIN || param < PARAM1_MAX)
            return true;
        else return false;
    }

    public void set setParam1(int param) {
        if(checkParam1(param))
            param1 = param;
    }
}
```

Now this seems to be an awful lot of code to simply set ONE parameter. Is there a more elegant, slim, and lean way to do this?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties

Comment: [Spring Default Property values](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-defaults)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use SpEL (Spring Expression Language), a very powerful tool :)

Than you can do something like this:

```
@Value("#{${my.param} > PARAM1_MIN || ${my.param} < PARAM1_MAX  ? ${my.param} : DEFAULT_PARAM1"})
private int param;
```

or perhaps more readable:

```
 @Value("#{checker.inRange(${my.param})}")
 private int param;
```

with a Component:

```
@Component("checker")
    private class PropertyChecker {
       public int inRange(int param) {
        ......
        }
    }
```

A nice tutorial is here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-expression-language
or : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use some validation constraints such as `@Max`, `@Min`, `@NotEmpty` and many other from package [java validation API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/package-summary.html)

see [Spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-validation).

here is an example :

```
public class User {

    @NotNull(message = "Name cannot be null")
    private String name;

    @AssertTrue
    private boolean working;

    @Size(min = 10, max = 200, message 
      = "About Me must be between 10 and 200 characters")
    private String aboutMe;

    @Min(value = 18, message = "Age should not be less than 18")
    @Max(value = 150, message = "Age should not be greater than 150")
    private int age;

    @Email(message = "Email should be valid")
    private String email;

    // standard setters and getters 
}
```

this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation) is much more detailed